# Como puedo solucionar el error que me arroja PHP 7.2 // Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated

Tags: php

Mi codigo es el siguiente, el error comienza en el while.

```
 function includeLang($Files)
   {
      global $LNG;
      while (list (,$File) = each($Files)){
         require(ROOT_PATH . "language/es/".$File.'.php');
         require(ROOT_PATH . "language/".$this->User."/".$File.'.php');
      }
   }
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el error completo como texto. Haz click en [editar] para editar la pregunta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso, podes solucionarlo usando [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), así:

```php
function includeLang($Files)
{
   global $LNG;
   foreach ($Files as $File) {
      require(ROOT_PATH . "language/es/" . $File . '.php');
      require(ROOT_PATH . "language/" . $this->User . "/" . $File . '.php');
   }
}
```